# Reading and printing zipfile name and filename inside the zipfiles using scala

Tags: scala

I have a directory with many *.zip files and each zipfile can have many *.xml files inside it.

```
Test1.Zip [2018-09-07 02-57-43Z-OJPRxx.xml , 2018-09-07 03-57-43Z-OJPRxx.xml ]

Test2.Zip [2018-09-17 02-57-43Z-OJPRYY.xml , 2018-09-17 03-57-43Z-OJPRYY.xml ]
```

Using the scala code I am able to print the name of the files inside the zip file , but cant print the name of the zip file itself - while using sc.binaryfiles and zipinputstreams.

I have altered the code that I researched and it appends the filename to each line of the xmlfile using the "getName" method. But I cant find any function in scala to print the parent zip filename after its builds the stream and starts to read zip files one by one.

```
 implicit class ZipSparkContext(val sc: SparkContext) extends AnyVal {

          def readFile(path: String,
                       minPartitions: Int = sc.defaultMinPartitions): RDD[String] = {

            sc.binaryFiles(path, minPartitions)
              .flatMap { case (name: String, content: PortableDataStream) =>
                val zis = new ZipInputStream(content.open)

                Stream.continually(zis.getNextEntry)
                  .takeWhile(_ != null)
                  .map { x ⇒
                    val filename1 = x.getName
                    scala.io.Source.fromInputStream(zis, "UTF-8").getLines.mkString(s"~${filename1}\n") + s"~${filename1}"
                  }

              }
          }
        }

        val df = sc.readFile("/landing/data/hs/tsnt/froff/bdu/acbdustore/INPUT/zipfiles", 1)

    df.saveAsTextFile("/landing/data/hs/tsnt/froff/bdu/acbdustore/INPUT/outputfile")

example output:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>~2018-09-06 01-57-43Z-OJPRQL.xml
<pnr  xmlns="http://gdsx.com/PnrDataPush.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">~2018-09-06 01-57-43Z-
OJPRQL.xml
    <PNRid>999999999999</PNRid>~2018-09-06 01-57-43Z-OJPRQL.xml
    <recordLocator>OJPRQL</recordLocator>~2018-09-06 01-57-43Z-OJPRQL.xml
    <GDS>6</GDS>~2018-09-06 01-57-43Z-OJPRQL.xml
    <platformID>NA</platformID>~2018-09-06 01-57-43Z-OJPRQL.xml
```

I expect my parent zip file name be captured and printed or written to an output file, but cant get a function/method to do the same. Would someone please help me out here. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It should be in 'name' or

```
content.getPath
```

Comment: Thank  you for your response, but the content.getpath returns only the XML filenames and not the parent ZIP filename and name is unrecognized. as mentioned in my original thread the .getName gives the XML filenames as well.

Comment: @Jana, sorry, usually I don't answer unless 100 %  sure. What do you mean by "name is unrecognized"?  If your code compiles, and your "case (name: String .." is there, then "name" must hold a value.

Comment: Hello Volty, I tested again "val zis2 = name" and indeed the name returns the parent zipfile name. thank you.